# Q: Android Remove Multi-User Button (No Root)

Tags: android, multi-user

Total newb here.

How would I go about removing the Multi-User icon/button from Quick Settings bar?

Screenshot:
[image]

Rooting is not an option, so I can't really alter system settings (like adding fw.max_users=1).

The purpose is to not allow the Owner user to create additional users. Settings are blocked with an AppLock app so it can't really be done there, but can via Quick Settings bar.

Can I remove the button by writing a script (Android Studio)?